# Тетрис на Android

Tags: java, android

Как усовершенствовать метод удаления заполненных линий? Чтобы заполненная линия изменялась на конкретную текстуру из класса Assets, а потом уже исчезала и опускалась вниз?

```
void deleteFullLines() {
    // поиск заполненной линии
    int firstFullLine = 0;
    boolean isFull = true;
    for (int i = 2; i <= 15; i++) {
        for (int j = 3; j <= 10; j++) {
            if (field[i][j] == null) {
                isFull = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isFull) {
            firstFullLine = i;
            break;
        }
        isFull = true;
    }
    // проверка заполненных линий
    int lastFullLine = 0;

    for (int i = 15; i >= 2; i--) {
        for (int j = 10; j >= 3; j--) {
            if (field[i][j] == null) {
                isFull = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        // удаление при наличии заполненных
        if (isFull) {
            for (int b = 10; b >= 3; b--) {
                field[i][b] = null;
            }

            lastFullLine = i;
            score+=20+levelScore;
        }
        isFull = true;

    }
    boolean fill = false;
    int fillLine = firstFullLine;
    // смещаем квадраты
    if (lastFullLine > 0) {
        for (int i = lastFullLine + 1; i < 15; i++) {
            for (int j = 3; j <= 10; j++) {
                if (field[i][j] != null) {
                    field[fillLine][j] = field[i][j];
                    field[i][j] = null;
                    fill = true;

                }
            }
            if (fill == true) {

                fillLine += 1;
            }
            fill = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: честно говоря, без контекста очень сложно серьезно упростить алгоритм

Comment: но как добавить спрайт или текстуру перед исчезновением линии? Как это реализовать?

Comment: пардон, но мне ваш код больше сортировку сложную напоминает, чем какую-то работу с графикой. Помочь вас не смогу.